# log4net override xml configuration?

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration

I am using log4net which is being configured via a config file. There is one case where I would like everything to be logged in debug (some code used during an upgrade). Is there anyway I can get the current logging level, set it to debug, run the specified code, then back to whatever it was before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a section in the  config file specifically for DEBUG using

```
 <logger name="MyApp.DebugLogging" additivity="false">
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
        <appender-ref ref="MainLog"/>
    </logger
```

Then in your code, you can access this logger using:

```
 private static readonly ILog debuglog = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("MyApp.DebugLogging");
```

And use the variable in your code block as

```
 debuglog .Debug(ex);
```

The idea here is you should be able to create different loggers in your config file, then have flexibility of choosing which logger to use within your code blocks

Comment: That's a fine solution. However, I'd rather use the existing loggers instead of creating a new logger just for the process described. Why? Because if you properly use the logging infrastructure, you should already have the `Debug` method in each logger. Change the logging level (or filter, whatever) **only in the config file**, and you'll have the benefit of viewing the `Debug` level without any new code to the system. New code is more maintenance and more potential bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea:

Use log4net configuration file only. Set the "watch" flag to true, in order to watch it.

Inside this configuration file, set a logging **filter** (in each appender). Set its min level to, say, `Info` or whatever. See the Filters section in http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html

Then, before the upgrade phase, edit the configuration file and change the filter's min level to, say, `Debug`.

Once the upgrade is done, set the filter's min level back to its original value.

Answer (score 1):

[This question discussed dynamic reconfiguration of Log4Net loggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738126/dynamically-reconfigure-log4net), which should give you the info you need.