# Query and modify log4net logger levels from code

Tags: log4net

I would like to create an area in my application that will let sysadmins modify logger levels directly.

[This answer from 2009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738126/dynamically-reconfigure-log4net) implies that I can do it with

```
foreach (ILog logger in log4net.LogManager.GetCurrentLoggers())
{
  ((log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger)logger).Level = 
      log4net.Core.Level.Error;
}
```

My application uses [log4net 2.0.3 (1.2.13)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net/) and this seems to not be available as no implementation of `ILog` inherits that class.

Instead I can grab each `ILog`'s `Logger` property for an instance of `ILogger`. This gives me the name but will not let me query or set the Level. While this is an ability that IS available on the implementation I cannot simply do a cast as the implementation is an internal class.

How do I do this in recent versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to grab the `Logger` property off of each `logger` and cast it as a `log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger`.

```
foreach (ILog logger in log4net.LogManager.GetCurrentLoggers())
{
    var log = logger.Logger as log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger;
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Level: {1}", log.Name, log.Level);
    log.Level = log4net.Core.Level.Error;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're right that you have to get each `ILog`'s Logger property: then you need to cast it to `log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger`.

`ILog.Logger` returns an `ILogger`, which as you've seen doesn't expose the writeable `Level` property, which I guess is considered to be an internal implementation detail.  But casting it to the concrete `log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger` type gives you access to what you need.

From the sample in the question whose answer you linked to:

```
foreach (log4net.ILog log in log4net.LogManager.GetCurrentLoggers())
{
    log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger logger = 
         (log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger)log.Logger;
    Debug.WriteLine(
        String.Format("{0} Parent {1} Level {2} EffectiveLevel {3}<br>",
        logger.Name,
        logger.Parent.Name,
        logger.Level == null ? "<null>" : logger.Level.Name,
        logger.EffectiveLevel
        )
        );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the full answer, this clarifies it