# Is it possible to create a debug logfile in code-only with Log4net

Tags: c#, log4net

Since it's for debugging purpose only I don't want to edit the app.config and the solution I've found online start by editing it. Is it possible to create a debug logfile only in code with Log4net?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following option.

```
((log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository()).Root.Level = Level.Debug;
((log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository()).RaiseConfigurationChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
```

You can find more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715941/change-log4net-logging-level-programmatically)