# How to turn off logging for a specific logger in Log4net

Tags: c#, logging, log4net, rollingfileappender, log4net-appender

I am using two `RollingFileAppenders` in my application and no root logger is used.  I need to turn on and off the logging programmatically during run time.

The below question is useful and it is working to turn off the root logger.
[Change log4net logging level programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715941/change-log4net-logging-level-programmatically)

How Can I enable/disable logging for a specific logger?

Comment: I found an answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/650924/5395773

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is working to set the logger level during run time.

```
 ((log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger)mylogger.Logger).Level = log4net.Core.Level.Debug;
```

You can get the `logger` using the below line of code.

```
LogManager.GetLogger("LoggerName")
```

Please find the actual answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/650924/5395773).